# Identify distinct mappings of two overlapping columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a Pandas dataframe with two identifier columns like this:

```
import pandas as pd

so_fake_data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'id_1': ['A', 'A', 'D', 'F', 'H', 'H', 'K', 'M'],
        'id_2': ['B', 'C', 'E', 'G', 'I', 'J', 'L', 'L']
    }
)
```

[image: Resulting so_fake_data df]

Suppose my interpretation of this table is:

- A is related to B
- A is also related to C
- D is related to E
- (and so on)

Using the first two points: If A is related to both B and C, I'd want to conclude that A, B, and C are all in the same group.

Essentially, I want to be able to identify these groupings...:

- A, B, C
- D, E
- F, G
- H, I, J
- K, L, M

... and then give them a grouping value in a new column like this, where I can distinguish each grouping:

[image: Hoping to create this]

I appreciate anyone's help on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a network issue, try with `networkx`

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'id_1', 'id_2')
l = list(nx.connected_components(G))
l
Out[66]: [{'A', 'B', 'C'}, {'D', 'E'}, {'F', 'G'}, {'H', 'I', 'J'}, {'K', 'L', 'M'}]
```

Then we can try

```
from functools import reduce
d = reduce(lambda a, b: {**a, **b}, [dict.fromkeys(y,x) for x, y in enumerate(l)])
df['g'] = df.id_1.map(d)
df
Out[76]: 
  id_1 id_2  g
0    A    B  0
1    A    C  0
2    D    E  1
3    F    G  2
4    H    I  3
5    H    J  3
6    K    L  4
7    M    L  4
```